# Is "forall elimination twice with the same fresh variable" allowed?

Tags: logic, proof-verification, predicate-logic, formal-proofs, natural-deduction

I am looking to prove that $\forall x \forall y \; P(x,y) \vdash \forall x \; P(x,x)$ and I wonder if this is allowed:
`1. ∀x ∀y P(x,y)             Premise
2. | x0                     fresh variable
3. | ∀y P(x0, y)            ∀-elimination (1)
4. | P(x0, x0)              ∀-elimination (3)
5. ∀x P(x, x)               ∀-introduction (4)`

It's the second forall elimination that I am worried about being incorrect. If this is not allowed, I would like to know why that is the case.

Comment: It's fine.${{}}$

Comment: @GitGud, do you happen to have a source of sort that points towards this? I am reading the book "Logic in Computer Science" by Huth and Ryan, but I cannot find anything that supports this.

Comment: The rules themselves support it. Sorry, I don't know about any source that singles out this issue specifically.

Comment: See page 109: "The rule] says: If $∀xφ$ is true, then you could replace the $x$ in $φ$ by **any** [emphasis added] term $t$ (given, as usual, the side condition that $t$ be free for $x$ in $φ$) and conclude that $φ[t/x]$ is true as well." When we have "nested" universal quantifiers, the condition still apply : **any** term $t$. The intuition is : "for all" means ... for all.

Answer (score 1):

Using the proof checker associated with *forallx*, both linked below, the proof as you presented it is correct.

Here is the proof:

[image]

For the second forall elimination any name may be used to stand for the variable $y$ including the name used for the first forall elimination of variable $x$.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Winter 2018. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/